# Crop Image black background issue in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an application where I have to take Image from camera and gallery, but when I an trying to crop the image I am getting some dark background into Image.  I am using this code for crop Image-

```
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
```

It is working okay, but problem is dark background behind the Image.
[image: my output image after crop]

Comment: Could you attach the picture? Make sure the output is PNG as others may not support opacity.

Comment: yes sure i am attaching..

Comment: yes I saw your answer thanks but its not help me.. Reason is that after crop the Image my Image size is reduce comparing to actual size that's why image display black background..
Now how can I keep actual effect of of Image with out black background?
Thanks for your kind help...

Comment: Try setting aspectX/aspectY to 1.

Comment: yes I try but in case of 1 my crop size is fix for every image. Any thing else please?

Comment: I think you just need to calculate the new size manually yourself before you resize it so that it agrees with the aspect ratio of the original image.

Answer (score 2):

```
// aspectX aspectY
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
//        outputX,outputY
intent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 1200);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true); That save me

Answer (score 1):

I made my ImageView like this, and it solved my problem :-

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectedpic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_d" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Important tags are
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` and   `andandroid:scaleType="centerCrop"`

I tried `intent.putExtra("scale", true);`
but if we scale a small part of image according to previous size, it degrade the image quality. So I do not recommend to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that the new size of the image is larger than the source, and when you are cropping it Android needs to "fill in" that new size with something.

You can have some logic to see if you need to crop an image or not in your code before cropping it.

Alternatively you can look into the [ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) library.